# React-Reduc's connect does not pass anything back to my component

Tags: redux, react-redux

So I'm a little stumped with React-Redux's connect, in that it seems to not pass anything back to my component.  I've been trying to debug this all morning now, and I've looked at a few tutorials but I can't see what I've done wrong.  Here's a snippet of the relevant code below.  Am I misunderstanding connect()?

```
const TodoList = (props) => {
    console.log(props); // Returns only an object with one property
                        // dispatch which holds a function.  Where        
                        // are my todos, filter, toggleTodo & removeTodo?
    return (
        <li> placeholder </li> 
    )
}

const RenderTodoGenerated = connect(
    todoStateToProps,
    todoDispatchToProps
)(TodoList);

const todoStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        todos: state.todos,
        filter: state.filter
    }
}

const todoDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        toggleTodo: (toggleId) => {
            dispatch(toggleTodo(toggleId));
        },
        removeTodo: (removeId) => {
            dispatch(removeTodo(removeId));
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ES6, variables declared with `const` do not exist until the line they're declared on.  Your call to `connect` occurs before `todoStateToProps` and `todoDispatchToProps` actually exist, so at that point they're undefined.  You need to move the call to `connect` to the end of that chunk of code.

Also, as an FYI, `connect` supports an "object shorthand" for handling the `mapDispatch` argument.  Instead of writing an actual function as you have in that example, you can simply pass an object full of action creators as the second argument, and they will be wrapped up with `dispatch`.  So, all you need is:

```
const actionCreators = {toggleTodo, removeTodo};
const RenderTodoGenerated = connect(todoStateToProps, actionCreators)(TodoList);
```

Comment: Ah ok, wow that did it.  I'm so use to variables being hoisted automatically to the top from pre ES6 days.  Guess it's time to brush up on my ES6'ness.  Thanks for the shorthand tip as well.  Cheers and thanks!